# UTF-8 text from database not appearing correctly in emails

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

We have a script the compiles emails for or foreign clients using a template and data from the database and sends it via Phpmailer.

The template is stored as a PHP file and opened as a string using `file_get_contents()`. Then a few `str_ireplace()` are used to insert data from the database before it's sent, ie:

```
$email_body = str_ireplace('[NAME]', $row['name'], $email_body);
```

Text from the template (UTF-8 is set in the HTML) appears with accents.  However data from the database (stored with the collation utf8_general_ci) does not show correctly with question marks inside diamonds showing instead of accents.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->AddAddress($to_email);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->From = $from_email;
$mail->AddReplyTo($reply_to);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $email_body;
$mail->AltBody = $email_body;
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    ....
```

How can I get the text from the database to show correct?  When viewing in PHPMyAdmin the text appears with accents, so it is being stored correctly.

Comment: Well, you should examine the emails you generate: what encoding is claimed for the text in there?

Comment: Also a side note: you appear to be sending html based emails. Those emails are a huge annoyance and major security thread. In 99% of all cases plain text emails are by far the better choice. http://www.georgedillon.com/web/html_email_is_evil.shtml

Comment: It's not urgent so I've been waiting for another to be sent (having since added my name to the BCC).

Comment: On the side note I would argue that half the cases in the link are no longer an issue (speed, internet connection, bandwidth and email readers).  In the countries we send emails to internet speeds and connectivity isn't an issue and most email readers allow HTML now.  Besides this is an email sent to our network members, it needs to look the part and having the main content as an attachment is not user friendly nor does it look professional. I understand the security threat, but it's the best choice in this scenario

Comment: I would reconsider the line of argument about an attachment not looking professional: that exactly is the most striking argument against html emails: typically only newcomers trying to appear "more professional" prefer insecure html emails to a clear, transparent and easy to handle attachment ;-) _Real_ professionals will not fall for that old trick: they look at what you do, not how your output looks. But just as you like.

Comment: About "most email readers" allowing html mail now: true, but _real_ professionals have deactivated that option, since it is a huge security gap. No professional would voluntarily expose himself just to enjoy a more shiny look of an html email.

Comment: When I said 'professional' I meant from a business image point of view. It's a matter of audience though, and a business choice.  If we sent our emails as an attachment our network members who are paying for the referrals we send them, they will say it's awkward.  If you then explain it's safer they will say, but big companies send fancy emails.

Comment: Ok, so your target audience are _not_ professionals, but consumer people who are little interested in security. Then you chose a valid decision: bling bling over sense, since customers ask for it. Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send a "SET NAMES UTF8" query to the database before building your mail ?

I had a similar problem on a table (stored with utf8_general_ci just like you) and despite the meta-tag in HTML, I couldn't get it to encode the text correctly. 
"SET NAMES UTF8" did the trick in my case.

Comment: doesnt this only work when submitting to the database? This email is built later as it needs to wait ten minutes in case extra non-compulsory info is submitted from the form's thank you page.